# Qual alternativa para substituir códigos em ASP por JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, asp

Tenho esse código em `asp` e `javascript`.

```
<%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);    
            <%end if%>
```

Preciso torná-lo mais limpo, sem as tags `asp`. O que passa é que eu tenho muita dúvida quando o assunto é `asp`. Bem, há uns dias atrás o colega TobyMosque me ajudou bastante em fazer algo semelhante. Não estou aqui pedindo que faça para  mim, senão estarei sempre perguntando, mas uma dica ou uma linha a ser seguida. Minha tentativa ficou nisso:

```
if()
var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || "";
var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>"
```

Não consegui terminar o `if` e também não sei se o `ou` está correto. Veja que há um `if` no `asp`, caso seja jurídico, carrega uma variável senão carrega outra variável. Fico pensando se eu matar o `if` do `asp` e colocar um `if` do `js`, se vai dar tilt. Também poderia fazer um ternário, mas como fazer isso numa declaração de uma variável. Faria no `if`, mas na declaração não sei se é possível(acho que não). Como eu faço, ou melhor, qual caminho a seguir?

Fazendo minhas tentativas aqui cheguei a esse código, mas não sei se estar certo, pois para testar terei que alterar muito mais coisas, mas apenas me digam. Esse é o caminho? Não matei 100% o `asp`, mas deu uma otimizada em relação ao `asp`.

```
var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = null;
var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = null;
<%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
   onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>" || onum_seq_proposta_ts = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>";
<%end if%>
```

Ok, em realidade as variáveis `txt_prefixo` e `txt_sufixo` são variáveis. Elas já sei como tratar. Veja como estão declaradas:

```
    var txt_prefixo = '';
    var txt_sufixo  = '';

  try{
       txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
       txt_sufixo  = '';
       ......
```

TobyMosque, é dessa forma que eu devo utilizar o object?

```
var txt_prefixo = '';
var txt_sufixo  = '';
window["objeto"] = null;


        var nome_campo_cod_ts_id = "<%= trim(nome_campo_cod_ts) %>";

        var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = null;
        var onum_seq_proposta_ts = null;
        var txt_chamada = "";

        var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts_id = "<%= trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj)%>" == "S";

        if(onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts_id)
            window[txt_chamada][txt_prefixo][onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts][txt_sufixo];
        else
            window[txt_chamada][txt_prefixo][onum_seq_proposta_ts][txt_sufixo];
```

Em realidade estou com grande dificuldade de eliminar esse `try..catch`, ou seja, substituir por um código javascript mais limpo:

```
try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);    
            <%end if%>
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        }
```

Esse `try..catch` está dentro desse if em ASP:

```
<%if trim(nome_campo_cod_ts)<> "" then%>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if trim(ind_tipo_proposta_pj) = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);    
            <%end if%>
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        }
    <% else %>
        try {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.form01.';
            txt_sufixo  = '';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_pj_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        } catch (e) {
            txt_prefixo = '.document.all[\'';
            txt_sufixo  = '\']';
            <%if ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "S" then%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_pj_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%else%>
                var onum_seq_proposta_ts    = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + '<%Response.Write prefixo%>num_seq_proposta_ts' + txt_sufixo);
            <%end if%>
        }
    <%end if%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por que você não escreve os valores das variáveis `ind_tipo_proposta_pj` `nome_campo_cod_ts` e `prefixo`  em campos `HTML` do tipo `hidden`, assim que o `ASP` é executado, aí você pode manipular com o javascript. Lembre-se de colocar os campos antes do código `JavaScript` pois assim o servidor já "escreveu" os campos com os valores e você vai poder manipulá-los em seguida com `JavaScript`:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" id="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" value="<%= trim(VARIAVEL_DO_ASP_TIPO_PROPOSTA) %>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="nome_campo_cod_ts" id="nome_campo_cod_ts" value="<%= trim(VARIAVEL_DO_ASP_NOME_CAMPO_COD_TS) %>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="prefixo" id="prefixo" value="<%= trim(VARIAVEL_DO_ASP_PREFIXO) %>"/>
```

Aí sim você usa tudo em JavaScript:

```js
var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = null;
var onum_seq_proposta_ts = null;
var txt_chamada = "";
var txt_prefixo = "";
var txt_sufixo = "";

var campo_ind_tipo_proposta_pj_que_veio_do_asp = document.getElementById('ind_tipo_proposta_pj').value;
var campo_nome_campo_cod_ts_que_veio_do_asp = document.getElementById('nome_campo_cod_ts').value;
var campo_prefixo_que_veio_do_asp = document.getElementById('prefixo').value;
var prefixo_do_banco_de_dados = (campo_prefixo_que_veio_do_asp + "" + campo_nome_campo_cod_ts_que_veio_do_asp)

if (campo_ind_tipo_proposta_pj_que_veio_do_asp == "S") {
  eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + prefixo_do_banco_de_dados + txt_sufixo);

} else {
  eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + prefixo_do_banco_de_dados + txt_sufixo);
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" name="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" id="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" value="S" />
<input type="hidden" name="nome_campo_cod_ts" id="nome_campo_cod_ts" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="prefixo" id="prefixo" value="document.write('ok');" />
```

O problema aí meu amigo é que tanto para pessoa física, como para pessoa jurídica a variável `onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts`  e `onum_seq_proposta_ts`    serão iguais. Porque se você olhar o código correspondente no script `ASP` original, as variáveis são as mesmas `<%Response.Write prefixo%><%Response.Write nome_campo_cod_ts%>`

Comment: Não pensei nisto. Pode ser uma boa saída sim, fica bem mais legível. Pode ser um caminho ou uma linha a ser seguida. Caso seja uma proposta PF, esse campo deverá vir com "N". Se eu coloco na página o value como "S", como ficaria caso seja uma proposta PF?

Comment: Na verdade se você olhar mais a cima o certo é colocar o `value` com a impressão do conteúdo da variável que está no `ASP`. Essa variável do tipo da proposta está no `ASP` (você leu do banco de dados ou um arquivo de texto, por exemplo, utilizando `ASP`), ou está em um campo `HTML` e essa página recebe essa variável ?

Comment: Vem do banco. O problema é que o site é muito grande, esse é apenas um módulo pelo que fomos contratados para dar manutenção. O site é bem antigo. Essa dúvida eu tenho. Se fixo o value como "S" e entra "N", ele muda o value, certo?

Comment: Acho que não estás entendendo @pnet. Eu só fixei o campo no código de exemplo, para que você possa testá-lo. Mas no seu aí, na sua página, você vai imprimir o valor do resultado da variável que veio do banco de dados, vou chamar ela de `TIPO_DE_PROPOSTA` e fazer o seguinte: `<input type="hidden" name="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" id="ind_tipo_proposta_pj" value="<%= trim(**TIPO_DE_PROPOSTA**) %>"/>`

Comment: Ok, entendi agora. Nesse caso ele mesmo vem do BD(ind_tipo_proposta_pj)

Comment: Ok editei o código, pois entendi o que o seu código original propunha. Ele além de verificar se o valor da variável `ind_tipo_proposta_pj` é pessoa jurídica "S", o código `JavaScript` das condições `if` e `else` executa o aglomerado de outras variáveis, algumas do banco (entendendo que o que vem do seu `ASP` veio do banco) e são elas `nome_campo_cod_ts` e `prefixo`, e outras do próprio `JavaScript` e são elas `txt_chamada`, `txt_prefixo` e `txt_sufixo`.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26947/discussion-between-maicon-herverton-and-pnet).

Answer (score 2):

pnet, aproveitando a ideia do Maicom, você pode colocar as variáveis dentro de uma tag script na sua pagina ASP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj = "<%= ind_tipo_proposta_pj %>";
    asp.prefixo = "<%= prefixo %>";
    asp.nome_campo_cod_ts = "<%= nome_campo_cod_ts %>";
</script>
```

Porem fazendo desta forma, você vai enfrentar o mesmo problema que colocando em input:hidden, o usuario poderá alterar o valor vindos do ASP.

Então você pode fazer o seguinte para travar estes valores:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var asp = {};
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "ind_tipo_proposta_pj", { value: "<%= ind_tipo_proposta_pj %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "prefixo", { value: "<%= prefixo %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
    Object.defineProperty(asp, "nome_campo_cod_ts", { value: "<%= nome_campo_cod_ts %>", writable: false, enumerable: true, configurable: true });
</script>
```

Agora que você tem todas estas variaveis em memoria, você pode trabalhar em um *.js separado.

```
var onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = null;
var onum_seq_proposta_ts = null;
if (asp.ind_tipo_proposta_pj.trim() === "S")
    onum_seq_proposta_pj_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts + txt_sufixo);
else
    onum_seq_proposta_ts = eval(txt_chamada + txt_prefixo + asp.prefixo + asp.nome_campo_cod_ts + txt_sufixo);
```

O problema do código acima é o uso do eval, eu particularmente não gosto de montar javaScript dinamicamente desta forma, então vamos abordar uma alternativa.

Quando falamos de javaScript no browser, todas as variáveis/funções globais são na verdade propriedades do objeto window.

Então todas as declarações abaixo são equivalentes:

```
var objeto = null;
window.objeto = null;
window["objeto"] = null;
```

no caso de uma chamada dinâmica, as duas primeiras formas não nos interessa, mas note a terceira, posso passar o nome da variável como uma objeto.

então no lugar de fazer algo assim:

```
var prefixo1 = "teste1.";
var prefixo2 = "teste2.";
var propriedade = "teste3";
var valor = eval(prefixo1 + prefixo2 + propriedade);
```

podemos ter algo assim:

```
var prefixo1 = "teste1";
var prefixo2 = "teste2";
var propriedade = "teste3";
var valor = window[prefixo][prefixo2][propriedade];
```

sendo que desta forma você pode avaliar o valor desta propriedade através do watch do browser (no caso do chrome/opera o "Chrome" DevTools [F12]).

Comment: Ok Toby, estou realmente fazendo avaliações e testes. tenho seguido o modelo anterior que você me ajudou(montou). Essa abordagem, meu líder gostou muito e disse que seguisse esse padrão. O Maicon não está fora dessa abordagem. Essa função é muito grande, eu postei uma pequena parte apenas, pois eu tenho que entender, aprender e fazer, por isso não postei tudo. Vou seguir a abordagem de ambos, fazer minhas devidas alterações e testar.

Comment: Apenas corrigindo uma informação anterior. Respondi que as chamadas asp vêm do banco, mas não, elas estão vindo do formulário chamador, dos campos, como uma CheckBox e etc... Apenas como subsídio.